# Can't bind to 'testing' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular

I have been trying to learn how to use Angular's @Input decorator and for some reason I cannot figure out what is wrong.

I have properly imported the FormsModule in my app component but I keep getting the above error. Can someone please help?

Do I have a typo somewhere that I just cannot see?

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RecipeComponent } from './components/recipe/recipe.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RecipeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe',
  templateUrl: './recipe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe.component.css']
})

export class RecipeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() testing;
```

**component.html**

```
  <ul class="ingredient-list">
    <li *ngFor="let list of lists; let i = index;"><input type="checkbox" [testing]="list.checked" (click)="verifyAllChecked(i)" >{{list.quantity}}<br>{{list.item}}</li>
  </ul>
{{testing}}
```

Comment: we use input for parent child communication, what is your parent or child?

Comment: @FatemeFazli Oh I see that may be the problem. My parent is app.component and the child is recipe.compoent. I was trying to use Input in the recipe.component only. Is this why it's not working?

Comment: so you should use something like ```<app-recipe [testing]="list.checked" ></app-recipe>``` in your parent html.

Comment: @FatemeFazliYep that did the trick. Thanks. I didn't understand that input is only used for parent/child communication.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put this code in your component.html

```
<input type="checkbox" (click)="verifyAllChecked(i)" >
```

and then add your component tag to the app component like:

```
<app-recipe [testing]="list.checked" ></app-recipe>
```

Answer (score -1):

Input tag does not have testing property binding that's why it throws below error

> Can't bind to 'testing' since it isn't a known property of 'input'